# Fancybox() on iPhone cannot zoom

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

we use `.fancybox()` for product images and a sizetable (all images)

It works fine on desktop and iPads

Only on the iPhone the product images are OK, but the sizetable is just too small to read

the question is :

- can I disable fancybox on one specific *class* and based on the screen size?
  or
- can I allow the fancybox to be zoomed and pinched or make it open like o normal picture as it would do on the iPhone? 
  (last option preferred)

Comment: You've tagged the question with both FancyBox and FancyBox 2.  Which one are you using as they are completely different in their implementations and features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I normally do for clients that want fancybox disabled on specific screen sizes is

1. Set my preferred screen size in a variable like

   ```
   var setfancybox = 480; // or whatever
   ```

   .... if the screen `width` is bigger than `480` I will enable the images to open in fancybox otherwise as normal images.
2. Code (html) my targeted elements with another *class* but `fancybox` like :

   ```
   <a class="modal" href="images/01.jpg">image 01</a>
   ```

   ... in this case I am using the *class* `modal` so I can manipulate my elements.
3. Write a *function* that checks the screen's `width` and dynamically add or remove the `fancybox` *class* to/from my `modal` selectors (it should run after the fancybox initialization script) like :

   ```
   var screenWidth, setfancybox = 480;
   // set fancybox class when screen size is > setfancybox value
   function checkScreen() {
       screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
       if (screenWidth > setfancybox) {
           // modal elements should open in fancybox
           if (!jQuery(".modal").hasClass("fancybox")) {
               jQuery(".modal").addClass("fancybox");
           }
       } else {
           if (jQuery(".modal").hasClass("fancybox")) {
               jQuery(".modal").removeClass("fancybox");
           }
       }
   }
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       $(".fancybox").fancybox();
       checkScreen();
   }); //ready
   ```
4. Optionally, you may want to run the `checkScreen()` *function* again if the `window` is resized (changed orientation!?) so you could do :

   ```
   $(window).resize(function () {
       clearTimeout(_resize);
       _resize = setTimeout(function () {
           checkScreen();
       }, 500); // setTimeout
   });
   ```

   ... **notice** we used `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` to avoid the *function* to be run several times during the `resize` process but until it stopped. It also assumes you previously declared the `_resize` variable as global.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m55npzu0/1/)**